# FuelPHP Get "Not null violation" on foreign key trying to insert into related model

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I'm trying to insert into the table of a model with multiple levels of HasMany relationships. Here's the breakdown so far

Customer->(HasMany)->Members->(HasMany)->Incomes

However, on when trying to insert into the Incomes table, I get a "Not null violation" with the foreign key from the Members table not being carried to Incomes. I know the most common problem is screwing up the $_has_many and $_belongs_to properties, but as far as I can tell they are fine. Plus, Just inserting into the Member table works fine so I know at least for the first layer it's working! The only thing I can think of is if since it's a second level down, it's screwing up because of that. Here's my code:

Relation Link (Member)

```
protected static $_has_many = array(
    'incomes' => array(
        'key_from' => 'id',
        'model_to' => 'Model_Income',
        'key_to' => 'member_id',
        'cascade_save' => true,
        'cascade_delete' => true,
    ),
);
```

Relation Link (Income)

```
protected static $_belongs_to = array(
    'member' => array(
        'key_from' => 'member_id',
        'model_to' => 'Model_Member',
        'key_to' => 'id',
        'cascade_save' => true,
        'cascade_delete' => true,
    ),
);
```

The Controller Code

```
// code to set up $customer
$customer->members[] = Model_Member::forge();
// set $member_vals here
$customer->members[0]->set($member_vals);
$customer->members[0]->incomes[] = Model_Income::forge();
// set $income_vals here
$customer->members[0]->incomes[0]->set($income_vals);
$customer->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem that comes to mind is that you're setting relations on **->members** and **->incomes** (plural), instead of **->member** and **->income** (singular).

I also prefer to do relations separately, instead of chaining them like you do. So, if you already have relations set when you're adding a new Member to Customer, or a new Income to Member, my guess is that the index will not be 0.

What if you try the following instead:

```
$member = Model_Member::forge($member_vals);
$income = Model_Income::forge($income_vals);

$member->income[] = $income;
$customer->member[] = $member;

$customer->save();
```

Does it work?

**Different suggestion:**

Since it appears that you're following the table/column naming convention, try only this:

```
// Model_Member
protected static $_has_many = array(
    'incomes'
);

// Model_Income
protected static $_belongs_to = array(
    'members' // plural, not singular like you seem to have
);
```

If you want more help, you should definitely show how you have the Member/Income models and tables.

Comment: I tried what you said, and it still gave me the same error.

The thing is, I have other model relations that use plural naming and they work fine, as well as the FuelPHP documentation also using plural for $_has_many, singular for $_belongs_to, and plural for the instantiation.

http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/relations/belongs_to.html
http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/relations/has_many.html

Comment: See my different suggestion

Comment: Quetzy Garcia has a point. In your question you name the relation 'member', yet in your controller code you access it as members[]. That can't be right.